# Can react-testing library pass through console.log messages?

Tags: reactjs, testing, react-testing-library

Some of my tests are working but the test to see if logging in works doesn't. In a browser it'd be easy to see why: I can see the DOM, see errors in the console ("GET 401 unauthorized", "received login token from the backend") but react-testing-library seems to hide all that.

It seems I first have to change my app to put things in the DOM instead of in the console, and then I can test the whole login procedure.

So, is there an option to watch console output? Or how can I debug this?

Comment: Wait, are you trying to hit a live authentication server during a unit test? Are you *not* mocking the API services for unit testing? Please try to update your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Reproducible Code Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your component and unit test code?

Comment: I guess it's more of an e2e test. This whole mocking stuff sounds complicated, we have a test account in the backend that's used for manual testing so I thought let's just use that. I can make an example but you're probably familiair with using `console.log` in a react application to debug it? it's really nothing special.

Comment: Yeah, RTL is really for unit testing. If your code is console logging then you can try [mocking the console](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jest-mock-console) and provide a custom implementation to access/read what is passed from within your unit tests.

Comment: maybe this article will be helpfull? https://dev.to/zirkelc/how-to-test-console-log-5fhd

Answer (score -1):

I figured it out, all the `console.log` messages are shown by `react-testing-libary` in the console, I wrongly assumed I had to do something special to get them to show. Also like Drew said maybe I shouldn't do e2e testing with this framework, so I added Cypress to the project for this.

Comment: Would you mind expanding on this? I can't seem to find the console.logs coming from the application (App.tsx for example) anywhere.